# Diameter of immersed surfaces with bounded from above mean curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, curvature

Is the following true? I cannot see a counterexample and it seems very intuitively clear, at least in the embedded case.

Claim:
Consider the set $S$ of closed immersed Riemann surfaces $\Sigma \subset (X,g)$ (I am particularly interested in spheres), with the magnitude of the mean curvature bounded from above by some $C>0$, where $X$ is also closed. Let $Vol(\Sigma)$ denote the area, and $Diam(\Sigma)$ the diameter. Then for every $\epsilon >0$ there is a $\delta>0$ s.t. if
$$Vol (\Sigma) < \delta,  \text{ then } Diam (\Sigma)< \epsilon $$ where $\Sigma \in S$.

I really just want to say here that diameter of $\Sigma$ can be assured to be arbitrarily small by requiring that its volume is small.

edit 1: For more clarity let me add that $\epsilon, \delta$ above are assumed to depend on $\Sigma, X, g$.

edit 2: $C$ should be upper bound for magnitude of the mean curvature.

Comment: You really need to sharpen your question:  For example, are you only considering *compact* surfaces $\Sigma$ without boundary?  Are you making any hypotheses on the ambient Riemannian manifold $(X,g)$?  Without some hypotheses such as these, it is hopeless to prove any such estimate, since counterexamples are easily constructed.

Comment: Yes sorry I meant everything to be compact without boundary of course, I edited to say closed.

Comment: And what about $(X,g)$?  If you take $X = \Sigma\times S^1$ and let $g$ be a product metric (for some metric on $\Sigma$), then $\Sigma\times\{1\}\subset X$ is totally geodesic (and embedded to boot), so the mean curvature is identically $0$, and yet there obviously is no relationship between the diameter of $\Sigma$ (and hence it's diameter in $X$) and its volume.

Comment: Edited again, does this help?

Comment: Sadly, no.  See my comment directly above.

Comment: In your example there is a lower bound on the volume for embeddings in the class of $\Sigma \times \{1\} \subset X$, so how can it be a counterexample?

Comment: I see that you have removed the function $f$ and replaced it by $\epsilon$ and $\delta$.  That changes the question completely.  You now aren't claiming (are you?) that $\delta$ can be chosen in terms of $\epsilon$ without regard to the geometry of $X$.

Comment: That's write I am not claiming that, so everything depends on the geometry of $(X,g)$. I would also be interested in the version of the question with $f$, (also depending on geometry) but it is not essential and probably too complicated.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/32474/discussion-between-yasha-and-robert-bryant).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I am interpreting your question correctly, this is true when the ambient space is Euclidean and the submanifold is closed (i.e. compact and without boundary).  To see this one may invoke a result of Topping that bounds the (intrinsic) diameter of a closed, immersed submanifold of dimension $m$ by the $L^{m-1}$ norm of mean curvature over the immersed submanifold, e.g. for a surface take the $L^1$ norm (this scales correctly).

For a general ambient Riemannian manifold, by isometricly embedding the ambient metric in Euclidean space, one should be able to get a related bound as long as the embedding (of the ambient space) has bounded mean curvature.

See this [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/75953/estimates-for-the-diameter-of-a-nice-surface/76014#76014) to a related question for the reference.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look, I have just slightly clarified the question I hope.

Comment: I think Topping indeed answers the question positively. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Consider the [helicoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helicoid), it has vanishing mean curvature.
Rescaling it, you can get arbitrary large volume inside the unit ball.
That is, diameter can not be bounded in terms of area.

A big piece from the helicoid can be closed by a surface with arbitrary small mean curvature. So you may assume that the surface is closed, moreover you can assume it is a sphere.

Comment: Can you please remove your answer it has nothing to do with the question.